# Spring Filter recursive redirects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I am trying to auto login user using my SSO system.

So, when user validated, Filter is still redirecting to itself again and again.

This is my Filter code:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sr;
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) sr).getSession(false);
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("accountName") != null) {
            fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
            return;
        }
        try {
            TicketInfo ticketInfo = sso.getTicketInfo(request);
            if (ticketInfo != null && (ticketInfo.getResult().equals(Result.SUCCESS)) && ticketInfo.getUserName() != null) {
                if (ticketInfo.getExpireDate().compareTo(new Date()) >= 1) {
                    String accountName = ticketInfo.getUserName();
                    if(session!=null){
                        session.setAttribute("accountName", accountName);
                    }
                    fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) sr1;

        response.sendRedirect("http://sso-login.test");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought that in this part of code

```
if (session != null && session.getAttribute("accountName") != null) {
    fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
    return;
}
```

Filter must stop redirecting and chain my request, but it looks like it still redirecting to sso-login.

Many thanks for attention.

PS I checked, session attribute account name is not null.

Comment: You should also do a return after the second `doFilter`.

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much @M.Deinum. Please, answer this question and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks you didn't call `fc.doFilter(sr, sr1)` at the end. response.sendRedirect has no meaning without using doFilter after it.